# Hybrid OF Ports on Allied Telesis Switches

Tags: openflow, switching

I have an Allied Telesis AT-IE340-20GP switch.
I want to make port (12 for example) a hybrid port.
With hybrid I mean it should be able to forward packets when communicating with a non-OpenFlow port (Layer 2 packet forwarding) and when communicating with an OpenFlow port (with OpenFlow rules).

AT  guidance Link: https://www.alliedtelesis.com/sites/default/files/documents/configuration-guides/openflow_feature_overview_guide.pdf

I am following the steps in the Allied Telesis Configuration guidance applying these commands to interface port1.0.12:

```
conf t
interface port1.0.12
switchport mode trunk ingress-filter disable
switchport trunk allowed vlan add 1,10
openflow
```

On these configs, packets are being forwarded with OpenFlow ports but not with non-OpenFlow ports.

If I disable OpenFlow and put VLAN 1 as the native VLAN with these commands

```
conf t
interface port1.0.12
no openflow
switchport trunk vlan native 1
```

I am able to forward packets between the trunk port and other access ports on VLAN 1 (default). But I can't (obviously) connect to OF ports.

Here are the OpenFlow configs

```
awplus#show openflow config

Bridge of0
Controller "tcp:10.0.1.70:6653"
is_connected: true
other_config: {aux_id="0", name=con1}
fail_mode: secure
datapath_type: system
Port of0
Interface of0
type: internal
Port port1.0.7
Interface port1.0.7
type: system
options: {ifindex="5007", mtu="1500", native_vlan="4089"}
Port port1.0.8
Interface port1.0.8
type: system
options: {ifindex="5008", mtu="1500", native_vlan="4089"}
Port port1.0.9
Interface port1.0.9
type: system
options: {ifindex="5009", mtu="1500", native_vlan="4089"}
Port port1.0.10
Interface port1.0.10
type: system
options: {ifindex="5010", mtu="1500", native_vlan="4089"}
Port port1.0.11
Interface port1.0.11
type: system
options: {ifindex="5011", mtu="1500", native_vlan="4089"}
Port port1.0.12
Interface port1.0.12
type: system
options: {ifindex="5012", mtu="1500", native_vlan="4089"}
```

Here are the Vlan configs

```
awplus#show vlan all

VLAN ID Name Type State Member ports
(u)-Untagged, (t)-Tagged
======= ================ ======= ======= ====================================
1 default STATIC ACTIVE port1.0.1(u) port1.0.2(u) port1.0.3(u)
port1.0.4(u) port1.0.5(u) port1.0.6(u)
port1.0.13(u) port1.0.14(u)
port1.0.15(u) port1.0.16(u)
port1.0.17(u) port1.0.18(u)
port1.0.19(u) port1.0.20(u)
4089 VLAN4089 STATIC ACTIVE port1.0.7(u) port1.0.8(u) port1.0.9(u)
port1.0.10(u) port1.0.11(u)
port1.0.12(u)
```

Any thoughts?